# Trying to link my program (libsvm.c and libsvm.h) with libsvm.cpp to do a simple prediction

Tags: c, machine-learning, linker, libsvm

I am trying to use LIBSVM to perform binary-class machine learning (2 class only) using C on Eclipse. Before I started using my training data, I tried running a simple XOR problem to see if my LIBSVM could predict the correct output value (which is a supposed to be +1).

However, after I built my project, I got errors such as "undefined reference to '_Heap_Begin'" , "undefined reference to '_Heap_Limit'" , "undefined reference to 'svm_train'" , "undefined reference to 'svm_predict'" and "undefined reference to 'svm_destroy_param'". It seems like the libsvm.c file is not linked to the libsvm.cpp file, even though I already #include "libsvm.h" in both libsvm.c and libsvm.cpp. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

libsvm.h:

```
#ifndef _LIBSVM_H
#define _LIBSVM_H

#define LIBSVM_VERSION 322

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern int libsvm_version;

struct svm_node
{
    int index;
    double value;
};

struct svm_problem
{
    int l;
    double *y;
    struct svm_node **x;
};

enum { C_SVC, NU_SVC, ONE_CLASS, EPSILON_SVR, NU_SVR }; /* svm_type */
enum { LINEAR, POLY, RBF, SIGMOID, PRECOMPUTED }; /* kernel_type */

struct svm_parameter
{
    int svm_type;
    int kernel_type;
    int degree; /* for poly */
    double gamma;   /* for poly/rbf/sigmoid */
    double coef0;   /* for poly/sigmoid */

    /* these are for training only */
    double cache_size; /* in MB */
    double eps; /* stopping criteria */
    double C;   /* for C_SVC, EPSILON_SVR and NU_SVR */
    int nr_weight;      /* for C_SVC */
    int *weight_label;  /* for C_SVC */
    double* weight;     /* for C_SVC */
    double nu;  /* for NU_SVC, ONE_CLASS, and NU_SVR */
    double p;   /* for EPSILON_SVR */
    int shrinking;  /* use the shrinking heuristics */
    int probability; /* do probability estimates */
};

//
// svm_model
//
struct svm_model
{
    struct svm_parameter param; /* parameter */
    int nr_class;       /* number of classes, = 2 in regression/one class svm */
    int l;          /* total #SV */
    struct svm_node **SV;       /* SVs (SV[l]) */
    double **sv_coef;   /* coefficients for SVs in decision functions (sv_coef[k-1][l]) */
    double *rho;        /* constants in decision functions (rho[k*(k-1)/2]) */
    double *probA;      /* pariwise probability information */
    double *probB;
    int *sv_indices;        /* sv_indices[0,...,nSV-1] are values in [1,...,num_traning_data] to indicate SVs in the training set */

    /* for classification only */

    int *label;     /* label of each class (label[k]) */
    int *nSV;       /* number of SVs for each class (nSV[k]) */
                /* nSV[0] + nSV[1] + ... + nSV[k-1] = l */
    /* XXX */
    int free_sv;        /* 1 if svm_model is created by svm_load_model*/
                /* 0 if svm_model is created by svm_train */
};

struct svm_model *svm_train(const struct svm_problem *prob, const struct svm_parameter *param);
void svm_cross_validation(const struct svm_problem *prob, const struct svm_parameter *param, int nr_fold, double *target);

int svm_save_model(const char *model_file_name, const struct svm_model *model);
struct svm_model *svm_load_model(const char *model_file_name);

int svm_get_svm_type(const struct svm_model *model);
int svm_get_nr_class(const struct svm_model *model);
void svm_get_labels(const struct svm_model *model, int *label);
void svm_get_sv_indices(const struct svm_model *model, int *sv_indices);
int svm_get_nr_sv(const struct svm_model *model);
double svm_get_svr_probability(const struct svm_model *model);

double svm_predict_values(const struct svm_model *model, const struct svm_node *x, double* dec_values);
double svm_predict(const struct svm_model *model, const struct svm_node *x);
double svm_predict_probability(const struct svm_model *model, const struct svm_node *x, double* prob_estimates);

void svm_free_model_content(struct svm_model *model_ptr);
void svm_free_and_destroy_model(struct svm_model **model_ptr_ptr);
void svm_destroy_param(struct svm_parameter *param);

const char *svm_check_parameter(const struct svm_problem *prob, const struct svm_parameter *param);
int svm_check_probability_model(const struct svm_model *model);

void svm_set_print_string_function(void (*print_func)(const char *));

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* _LIBSVM_H */
```

libsvm.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "libsvm.h"
#include "main.h"
#define Malloc(type,n) (type *)malloc((n)*sizeof(type))

struct svm_parameter param;     // set by parse_command_line
struct svm_problem prob;        // set by read_problem
struct svm_model *model;
struct svm_node *x_space;
struct svm_node ** x;
struct svm_node *testnode;

void makeModel2(void)
{
    param.svm_type = C_SVC;
    param.kernel_type = RBF;
    param.degree = 3;
    param.gamma = 0.5;
    param.coef0 = 0;
    param.nu = 0.5;
    param.cache_size = 100;
    param.C = 1;
    param.eps = 1e-3;
    param.p = 0.1;
    param.shrinking = 1;
    param.probability = 0;
    param.nr_weight = 0;
    param.weight_label = NULL;
    param.weight = NULL;


    //Problem definition-------------------------------------------------------------
    prob.l = 4;

    //x values matrix of xor values (training data)
    double matrix[prob.l][2];
    matrix[0][0] = 1;
    matrix[0][1] = 1;

    matrix[1][0] = 1;
    matrix[1][1] = 0;

    matrix[2][0] = 0;
    matrix[2][1] = 1;

    matrix[3][0] = 0;
    matrix[3][1] = 0;

    // this part i do not understand
    struct svm_node** x = (struct svm_node * *)malloc((prob.l)*sizeof(struct svm_node *));

    //Trying to assign from matrix to svm_node training examples
    for (int row = 0;row <prob.l; row++){
        struct svm_node* x_space = Malloc(struct svm_node,3);
        for (int col = 0;col < 2;col++){
            x_space[col].index = col;
            x_space[col].value = matrix[row][col];
        }
        x_space[2].index = -1;      //Each row of properties should be terminated with a -1 according to the readme
        x[row] = x_space;
    }

    prob.x = x;

    //yvalues
    prob.y = (double *)malloc((prob.l)*sizeof(double));
    prob.y[0] = -1;
    prob.y[1] = 1;
    prob.y[2] = 1;
    prob.y[3] = -1;

    //Train model---------------------------------------------------------------------
    struct svm_model *model = svm_train(&prob,&param);


    //Test model----------------------------------------------------------------------
    struct svm_node *testnode = (struct svm_node *) malloc((3)*sizeof(struct svm_node));
    testnode[0].index = 0;
    testnode[0].value = 1;
    testnode[1].index = 1;
    testnode[1].value = 0;
    testnode[2].index = -1;

    double retval = svm_predict(model,testnode);

    svm_destroy_param(&param);
    free(prob.y);
    free(prob.x);
    free(x_space);

}
```

Comment: How do you build your program? Are you linking with the actual *library*?

Comment: I just added libsvm.cpp under the source (src) folder, the same source folder which has my libsvm.c. All of the svm_train and svm_predict etc. functions are in the libsvm.cpp source code, but my libsvm.c codes cannot enter the function because there is a "undefined reference error".

Comment: But how do you *build* the program? Are you building from the command line? What commands and options are you using? Are you building inside an IDE? In that case have you added all needed source files to the project (in the IDE)? Please *edit your question* to include all those details. And if you build from the command line, then copy-paste all the commands, options *and* output ***as text*** to put into the question.

Comment: Yes, I am building inside the Eclipse IDE and I have added all the needed source files to the project. Sorry for not clarifying earlier.

Comment: If you compile an x.c and an x.cpp file in the same directory, they will both produce an x.o (or x.obj) file. Overwriting each other...

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "same directory"? And also could you please explain how I could resolve this issue to prevent any overwriting? Thanks!

Comment: Do you remember Don Quijote? Don't try to convince your build tool (or IDE) to build `svm.c` and `svm.cpp` together. Just rename one of them e.g. `svm.cpp` to `svmpp.cpp`. Beside of this they may include both `svm.h`. It's not a rule of language C (nor C++) that source and header must have the same file name. It's only a usual convention (and I already saw some sources where they didn't follow this convention).

Comment: I changed the file name to a different name as you suggested, and there were no more "undefined reference to ...." errors. However, now there are errors "template with C linkage" in the svm.cpp file. Does this have anything to do with the link between C and C++? I do not understand the problem. Thanks!